# Dealing with with ties on a voting program

Tags: python

I am required to make a voting system as a project and I have gotten everything done except dealing with ties. The voting system for each amount of candidates is as follows. (there can be a maximum of 4 candidates)

```
            vote = input("who are you going to vote for? "+ CandidateName[0]+" or "+CandidateName[1]+"? or would you like to abstain from the vote?")
            while vote !=CandidateName[0] and vote != CandidateName[1] and vote != "abstain":
                print("This candidate doesnt exist. Please make sure you have spelled the name correct.")
                vote = input("who are you going to vote for? "+ CandidateName[0]+" or "+CandidateName[1]+"? or would you like to abstain from the vote?")
            if vote == CandidateName[0]:
                candidate1 = candidate1 + 1
                TotalVotes = TotalVotes + 1
            if vote == CandidateName[1]:
                candidate2 = candidate2 + 1
                TotalVotes = TotalVotes + 1
            if vote == "abstain":
                abstained = abstained + 1
```

I have a plan on how to do a vote again between the tied candidates but I don't really know how to see a tie. I do have percentages but I don't know if they can help with a tie. I would appreciate an example on how to check for a tie. My variables for the amount of votes a candidate gets is as such:

```
candidate1 = 0
candidate2 = 0
candidate3 = 0
candidate4 = 0
abstained = 0
TotalVotes = 0
```

I am a beginner at python so please don't judge my over usage of if statements.

Comment: `if candidate1 == candidate2` these candidates have the same number of votes.

Comment: Maybe you can use `itertools` and `permutations` to create all combinations of candidates, and then apply the logic on those pairs as suggested by @ThomasWeller. Of course, if you always have four candidates it might be easier to just hand-roll those pairs.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that did make sense but then wouldnt i have to make 12 different if statements?

Comment: @Quizzarex how would I implement itertools and permutations to my code?

Comment: You said: "please don't judge my over usage of if statements." so I thought you would just write 6 if-statements. If you do it in a different way, you would sort the list by votes and then just compare rank 1 against rank 2

Answer (score 0):

Very crude example on how you could utilise `itertools` and `permutations`

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> candidate_votes = [1,2,3,4]
>>> perm = permutations(candidate_votes, 2)
>>> for p in perm: print(p)
```